# Pause loader for testing purposes

Tags: android, testing, android-asynctask, android-espresso

I have the following code in my activity:

```
protected void load() {
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<BaseResource[]> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    final AsyncTaskLoader<BaseResource[]> loader = new AsyncTaskLoader<BaseResource[]>(this) {
            // ....
    };
    loader.forceLoad();
    loaderView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<BaseResource[]> loader, BaseResource[] data) {
    loaderView.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

and I want to test that the loaderView is really shown during the loading process. I'm using the **Espresso** tool and I have the following test method:

```
@SmallTest
public void testShowLoading() {
    getActivity().load();
    assertTrue(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loading_view).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE); // can't use espresso here since it waits for the loader to finish.
}
```

But this solution is flaky, sometimes the loader finishes too fast and the assertion fails. How can I make the loader to run for a longer time for the testing purpose? Is there any way to do this without modifying the activity code?

Comment: Please elaborate on your comment "can't use espresso". Why?

Comment: Event if your loader does not stop you will still have a problem. Given that Espresso waits for the view to be idle, if your loader keeps "spinning" Espresso will not evaluate the view because the view is never idle. The result will be a timeout.

Comment: I'm experiencing this right now, how were you able to go around this?